# Some questions about <uri> in sdf files

Tags: gazebo-all-versions, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi to all.

I was reading the Gazebo documentation and I have some questions to which I was not able to find an answer neither in the documentation nor on the forums.

As far I as I have understood, Gazebo has a bunch of environmental variable that expand to a list of path in the system to look for files. Copy pasting from my notes we have:

- `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`: colon-separated set of directories where Gazebo will search for models
- `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`: colon separated set of directories where Gazebo will search for other resources such as world and media files
- `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI`: uri of the gazebo master. This specifies the IP and port where the server will be started and tells the clients where to connect to.
- `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`: colon-separated set of directories where Gazebo will search for the plugin shared libraries at runtime
- `GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_PATH`: URI of the online model database where Gazebo will download model from

Now, when we build a model using an sdf file, we can use the tag `<uri>path_to_resource</uri>` to look for specific resources, such as meshes, models and so on.
In the documentation and online tutorial, I have often found things like

```
<uri>model://path</uri>
```

or

```
<uri>file://path</uri>
```

Now, I guess that `model://` is just a place holder for `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.

My questions are:

1. what does `file://` correspond to?
2. Are there any other place holder I have not yet seen?
3. Can you point me to a place in the documentation where this place holders are defined?

Thanks for your time and patience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29153/some-questions-about-%3Curi%3E-in-sdf-files/) by [biagio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/190231/biagio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had a further look:

**Wrt. `model://`:**

Based on [this  documentation](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/tutorials/migration_sdf.md#path-relative-to-an-environment-variable), I conclude that `model://` is replaced by:

- `GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH` for **Gazebo Sim**, and
- `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` and/or `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` for **Gazebo Classic**

I cannot find the latter two in the Gazebo Sim source code, so these seem for Gazebo Classic only.

**Wrt. `file://`:**

Based on [this comment in the code](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-common/blob/6a0f9d7cd67a3916a0e6661cd99494f2d0e4faf9/include/gz/common/URI.hh#L35-L54) (for **Gazebo Sim**, not sure about Classic), I conclude that `file://` can be followed by either a relative path or an absolute path.

[Lines 43-47](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-common/blob/6a0f9d7cd67a3916a0e6661cd99494f2d0e4faf9/include/gz/common/URI.hh#L43-L47) of the comment contradict with [line 53](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-common/blob/6a0f9d7cd67a3916a0e6661cd99494f2d0e4faf9/include/gz/common/URI.hh#L53) but I can confirm that -for my use case- `file://rel/path` seems to work just fine for a relative path.

**Wrt. other environment variables:**

A grep through the source code of **Gazebo Sim** yields following list. The `IGN` ones are deprecated in Garden

```
GZ_FILE_PATH
GZ_GUI_PLUGIN_PATH
GZ_GUI_RESOURCE_PATH
GZ_LAUNCH_CONFIG_PATH
GZ_LAUNCH_PLUGIN_PATH
GZ_PLUGIN_PATH
GZ_RENDERING_PLUGIN_PATH
GZ_SIM_PHYSICS_ENGINE_PATH
GZ_SIM_RENDER_ENGINE_PATH
GZ_SIM_RESOURCE_PATH
GZ_SIM_SERVER_CONFIG_PATH
GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH
IGN_FILE_PATH
IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH
IGN_GAZEBO_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH
IGN_GUI_PLUGIN_PATH
IGN_LAUNCH_CONFIG_PATH
IGN_LAUNCH_PLUGIN_PATH
IGN_PLUGIN_PATH
IGN_RENDERING_PLUGIN_PATH
SDF_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) with karma: 31 on 2023-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [biagio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/190231/biagio/) on 2023-06-22**:
Thank you very much for the help! I also had a look in these days at the other discussion you linked https://osrf-migration.github.io/sdformat-gh-pages/#!/osrf/sdformat/pull-requests/558/page/1

As far as I understood, in Gazebo Classic it worked like this:

- models:// was replaced by`GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`
- file:// was replaced by `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`

The behavior of Gazebo Sim for file:// was changed to respect some standard about URI files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme